# Generic Constructor call in inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have the following scenario :

```
public abstract class A{}

public class B extends A{}


public abstract class C<T extends A>{
    private T t;
    public C(){}
    public C(T t){
        this.t = t;
        }
}

public class D<B> extends C<A>{
     private B b;
     public D(B b){
        super(b);
        this.b=b;
       }
}
```

But i am getting an error in the constructor of class D. What am i missing? Java 1.7

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: compilation error in the super call

Comment: What's the the error message???

Comment: You're missing `C`'s generic type parameter in `extends C`

Comment: incidentally i tried -> public class D<T extends B> extends C{} <- and it worked, but i want D to be a generic of only B and not its child classes if any

Comment: You probably meant `D extends C<B>`.

Comment: @khelwood tried it but didnt work; please see the edit

Comment: "I got an error" and "it didn't work" are not adequately describing problems.

Comment: @khelwood it's a compilation error, and a logical one. Nothing much i can say about it.

Comment: Really. So when the compiler fails it just says "I have error". It doesn't give you any indication of what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you gave, `B` (the generic parameter of `D`) doesn't have to extend `A` so the bound of generic parameter from `C` is not satisfied.

Change `D<B> extends C` to `D extends C<B>`.